# Two different SSID's on the same chanel. Is it safe?

Tags: monitoring, wifi, hacking

If I have multiple network, that have their SSID's on the same channel, can I go into monitor mode(of the wifi interface) and capture packets of the other SSID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go into monitor mode and capture packets of **any** WiFi network in range. But you won't be able to decrypt them easily unless you have the PSK of the wifi network, or a supercomputer.

Comment: what if they are unprotected networks?

Comment: Well then there wouldn't be any decryption to do.

Comment: You mean that if I'm on monitor mode, and I have an unprotected wifi network in range, I can capture all its traffic ?

Comment: @user3465593 yes. Though doing that if it's not your own network will get you in trouble.

Comment: I have to stop using my neighbours unprotected network in that case :P. When the passwords travel over the network, I'm hoping they are encrypted(for instance the gmail password).

Comment: Definitely. I hope they know you are using their network. Also Passwords aren't always encrypted. POP3 for example doesn't encrypt passwords.

Comment: There is this misunderstanding fundamentally that WIFI is not a radio network. Anyone in range dcan record anything sent on radio. Radio also does not stop at office boundaries or the end of your piece of land ;) And capturing I can do over quite long distances with the right antenna equipment.

Comment: do not use an untrusted wireless network unless you want the people running it to know everything you're doing (in fact on a trusted one, they'll still probably know but you're trusting them not to use that info to be mean to you). Do not use an unencrypted WLAN for anything important full stop.